# Is there a Checkstyle/PMD rule "Non-abstract classes should not be named AbstractXXX"?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle, pmd

The Java project I'm working on uses a combination of code analysis tools: PMD, Checkstyle and FindBugs. These pick up on plenty of bugs, style issues etc. but one often slips through the net:

```
public class AbstractBadlyNamedClass { // Not abstract!
    // ...
}
```

Note the other way round *is* checked, i.e. `public abstract BadlyNamedClass` gives PMD warning "Abstract classes should be named AbstractXXX".

Could anyone advise whether there is a way of checking for this, either with one of the mentioned tools (perhaps some kind of custom rule?) or another automated tool that would do the job?

Comment: How about "search" in Eclipse?

Comment: I would actually support reversing it.  There are plenty of reasons to not name an abstract class `AbstractXXX`.  But a class named `AbstractXXX` better be abstract!  Otherwise, you will confuse little old me :)

Comment: @Antoniossss - That would work but its hardly automated and not something thats easy to roll into a continuous integration process.

Comment: You want some kind of mass refactoring?

Comment: @Antoniossss no just something that runs as part of the Eclipse and Maven build.

Comment: And to mass refactor your code?

Comment: No, just raise warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the checkstyle [AbstractClassName](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#AbstractClassName) check is what you are looking for.